# Title attribute not working on a command button with Disabled = true in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-button

I have a lightning-button and want to display a tooltip/hover text whenever the button's disabled attribute is true.

```
<lightning-button variant="brand" label="Test Button 1" data-value={test1.Id} title={showTitleOnDisable} disabled={isFileDownloadable}>
```

Below is the getter function to choose the title text:

```
get showTitleOnDisable(){
        if(!this.isFileDownloadable){
            return 'Test successful';
        }else{
            return 'Error';
        }  
    }
```

The above code works well when disabled attribute evaluates to false but there is no output in case button is disabled.

Is this some kind of a limitation in HTML?
Is there any alternative to achieve this functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative, You can use Lightning Design System to achieve it:-

```
<template>
    <button class="slds-button slds-button_neutral" title="showTitleOnDisable" disabled={isFileDownloadable}>Test Button 1</button>   
</template>
```

It works in both case.

Comment: Thanks Sanket! for pointing me towards the LDS approach. My first preference was to build it through the native LWC tags but its always good to get things working!!!